# How to pass model attributes globally to avoid repeatable code in Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to ask you for some best practice to reduce the amount of repeatable code in my controller's methods - one of them is presented below.

I have quite a big and complex view with a lot of information and two forms. In every method of my controller (and there are quite a few) I have to pass the same attributes to my view (in post controllers even twice). I added a note SAME CODE in the code snippet below indicating identical pieces of code.

I wonder if there is any possibility to make a one global method in the controller gathering all attributes to be passed to the model and just reference it in any of particular methods?

I looked into ModelAndView or ModelMap, but cannot see those being suitable here.

Just want to avoid repeating this part:

**Repeatable piece of code**

```
model.addAttribute("hotels", hotelService.getAllHotels());
List<GetRoomDto> roomsDto = roomService.getAllRoomsByHotelId(hotelId);
model.addAttribute("rooms", roomsDto);
model.addAttribute("roomTypes", roomTypeService.findAllRoomTypeNames());
```

**Full method with that piece of code appearing twice**

```
@PostMapping("/hotels/{hotelId}/rooms")
    public String createRoomForHotelById(@ModelAttribute("room") @Valid NewRoomDto roomDto,
                                         BindingResult result,
                                         @PathVariable("hotelId") Long hotelId,
                                         Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            // SAME CODE
            model.addAttribute("hotels", hotelService.getAllHotels());
            List<GetRoomDto> roomsDto = roomService.getAllRoomsByHotelId(hotelId);
            model.addAttribute("rooms", roomsDto);
            model.addAttribute("roomTypes", roomTypeService.findAllRoomTypeNames());
            //
            
            model.addAttribute("hotel", new NewHotelDto());
            LOG.info("Binding error: {}", result.toString());
            return "admin/dashboard";
        }
        
        // SAME CODE
        model.addAttribute("hotels", hotelService.getAllHotels());
        List<GetRoomDto> roomsDto = roomService.getAllRoomsByHotelId(hotelId);
        model.addAttribute("rooms", roomsDto);
        model.addAttribute("roomTypes", roomTypeService.findAllRoomTypeNames());
        //
        
        LOG.info("AdminController: CreateRoomForHotelById: Created room: {}", roomDto.toString());
        
        roomDto.setHotelId(hotelId);
        roomService.createNewRoom(roomDto);
        
        return "redirect:/auth/admin/hotels/{hotelId}/rooms";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also move the code from [J Asgarov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63401405/9842523) into the same controller instead of another class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. That way that code will only be executed for `@RequestMapping` methods within that controller.

For multiple values you could also do something like this:

```java
@ModelAttribute
public void foo(Model model, @PathVariable(required = false) Long hotelId) {
        model.addAttribute("hotels", hotelService.getAllHotels());
        if (hotelId != null) {
            List<GetRoomDto> roomsDto = roomService.getAllRoomsByHotelId(hotelId);
            model.addAttribute("rooms", roomsDto);
        }
        model.addAttribute("roomTypes", roomTypeService.findAllRoomTypeNames());
}
```

But seeing your code I would rather suggest you move the repeated code into a private method and call it whenever you need those inside your model.
Your method `createRoomForHotelById` for example causes a redirect, which basically discards everything you put in your model.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm gonna implement that :)

Answer (score 1):

For global model attributes you can use @ControllerAdvice:

Create a class and annotate it with `@ControllerAdvice`.
Inside of that class pass the model attribute (which will now be available globally) like so:

```
@ModelAttribute("foo")
public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}
```